# High stock chart navigator accessed with keyboard after facing navigation issue in kendoWindowPopup

Tags: highcharts, kendo-window

high stock chart navigator accessed with keyboard after facing navigation issue in kendoWindowPopup here below listed facing some issues also attached demo.

1. Focus does not move backward using the shift + tab keyboard navigation while the focus is on the range selector.
2. In the compact view focus is getting stuck and not moving forward from the range selector of the timeline chart.
3. At the end of the timeline chart one hidden element gets focused which can not be removed.

Example Link : [Example Link](https://dojo.telerik.com/@vimal_mavani/exeVEJet/7)

i've try to prevent event but it's not working

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this, I can freely move around the chart using the keyboard. Can you send a GIF or video showing the problem? What browser, operating system and version are you using?

Comment: Hi Michał, You can refer to my DOJO link, i can provide code also
https://dojo.telerik.com/@vimal_mavani/exeVEJet/7